# What is best pattern to have partitions for a table having a "language_id" AND a "category_id"?

Tags: database, postgresql

Consider a *Postgres* table which contains articles (or posts) having a `language_id` as a reference on the languages-table and a `category_id` as reference on the category-table. There will be only one category per post.

```
create table posts
(
    id              serial
        constraint "PK_2f5e6c9d57ae96fad69b6f97bd5"
            primary key,
    uuid            varchar(64)             not null,
    language_id     integer
        constraint "FK_6ae668385245848a0ce7220504a"
            references public.languages,
    category_id     integer
        constraint "FK_04472151c4fa89d9905711a3c38"
            references public.category,
    ...
```

There will be 8 languages to be supported and approx. 7 main categories, which leads to `language_id IN (1..8)` and `category_id ON (1..7)`.

There is a little chance, that in a year or so we'll support another language or that even another category will be introduced.

I am thinking about what is the best approach to build partitioned tables?

The goal is to

a) SELECT all posts by language
b) SELECT all posts by language AND a specific category

Given the fact, that we have around 1 mio posts in the database, partition could speedup things.

Would I only build partitions for the language_id as this one will be the main criteria for any selection of posts?
Would I build sub-partitions per language AND per category_id?
Shall I use `PARTITION BY LIST (language_id)` as partition or rather HASH or something else? The same question exists for the category_id related partitions.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: The first question: Are there any queries across multiple languages? If not, you might as well have 8 (or later more) separate tables and keep things simple. (Still keep the exact same structure to avoid complicating queries.)

Comment: For just a million posts or records, I wouldn’t spend a second on table partitioning. You don’t have a performance problem and it’s unlikely you run into one either

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter only one specific language will be queried all the time ("show all articles from today, last 24 hours, in japanese")

Comment: @FrankHeikens the ugly truth is: i already have. That's why I am seeking for optimization guidelines

Comment: If you have a performance problem, please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statements and the full DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text

Comment: Partitioning is not primarily a performance feature. But it can speed up sequential scans. So if you really have to fetch **all** posts for a certain language, partitioning might help a bit. But for really good performance, you'd need pre-aggregated data. Yes, please show us the actual query and its execution plan.